# Bootstrap Datepicker change default view date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a bootstrap datepicker and I want to set the defaultViewDate option (http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#id3).  It all works fine if I set it at instantiation like this:

```
jQuery(element).datepicker({
    defaultViewDate: {year: 2000}
});
```

The trouble is that I want to have the default view (*not the value*) update in response to user input.  I'm including this as part of an angular app on a page so I was hoping there would be a way to leverage data-binding here.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) has a datepicker directive that sounds like it can do what you want.  In the example they have, they change the default view by way of buttons at the bottom of their example.